# How to remove element from queue without deleting it

Tags: system-verilog

I have a queue of classes and I need to remove an element that may be in the middle of the queue without deleting the element. I can't use pop_front/pop_back since the element may be in the middle of the queue, but it looks like if I use `delete(index)` it deletes the element (which I don't want to happen since the element is used in other queues that still persist). Is there anyway I can accomplish this? I'm thinking I could create an entirely new queue and copy over all the other elements, but that seems like a lot of effort and may be inefficient especially if the queue is large.

```
class myclass;
    //...
endclass

myclass my_q[$];
myclass my_other_q[$];

module tb;

    initial begin
        myclass a = new();
        my_q.push_back(a);
        my_other_q.push_back(a);
        remove_my_q_element(0);
        //Here I expect my_q to no longer have object 'a', but my_other_q still should have object 'a'
    end

    function void remove_my_q_element(int index);
        //???? Don't do this since it seems the object at my_q[index] will be deleted
        //my_q.delete(index);
    endfunction

endmodule
```

Comment: Updated with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Can you treat the queue as as array instead in this case.  It will work that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the concept of a class object, its handle, and the variable(element) where the handle get stored.

Your queue is an array of class variables where each element holds a handle to a class object. If you delete an element of the queue using `my_q.delete(index)`, you are deleting a variable holding a handle to the class object, not the object itself. If there are other queues or any other variable storing a handle to that object, the object will not get deleted. Objects get deleted only *after* there are no longer any handles to an object stored in any class variables.

See my [Short Class on SystemVerilog Classes](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/07/16/class-on-classes/).